# Spring JsonIgnore annotation doesn't work in Map

Tags: java, spring

So I'm working in Java, Spring. I have an entity called Pizza, that has two realtionships, one of them is a Set of Ordered Pizzas. Those have @JsonIgnore annotation, and it does work if I just want to return a List of Pizzas, or just one pizza.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

@Entity
@Table(name = "pizza")
public class Pizza implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
....
@JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "pizza")
    private Set<OrderedPizza> oPizza;
```

However, now I want to return a `HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Pizza>>`, and when I do, every single field of Pizza is visible, even though they still have `@JsonIgnore` annotation. What am I doing wrong? Is there a solution? Also, this `oPizza` doesn't have a getter so it shouldn't even be visible at all.

Comment: For relationship's objects you need to use `@JsonBackReference`(not include in serialization) and `@JsonManagedReference`(included)

Comment: Thanks for the info, but unfortunately my response is still the same size (77.5MB) and still contains 'oPizza' after using '@JsonBackReference'. I think it has something to do with using a List in the Map.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below :

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnore;
```